# Lose Focus on JTextField when clicking on the panel

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel, jtextfield

I want to lose the focus on a JTextField when the user is clicking on the main panel.

`setFocusable(true)` doens't work for me.

If I am clicking on the main panel, the JTextField has still the focus and you can enter stuff.

Note: My JFrame is set to focusable (true).

Comment: Try adding a mouse listener to the pane and call `requestFocusInWindow` when `mouseClicked` is called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think since you want to get the focus on clicking the main panel, you should implement a simple `MouseListener` to do the job for you. Again since the panel (main panel) is added to the `JFrame` or rather it's set as the content pane, that is the place where `setFocusable(true);` should be called. The code below should sort out the problem :

```
       mainPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseReleased(e);
                Focus.this.grabFocus();
            }
        });
```

Please note that `Focus` is the name of my class and am extending the `JPanel` before adding it to the `JFrame`.

Comment: This is working, thanks for that. Now I have the problem that my KeyListener is not triggering, when I'm entering some keys. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Which keys are you talking about?

Comment: Keyboard keys like aklsdfjelwötqew1234167876978raf

Comment: I think its an internal error, which is caused by my quellcode and not from the Jlibs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: nitpicks: a) whether or not you want to get the focus in a mouseClicked (vs. a mousePressed as more often done), the super super method to call is not not released b) the adapter is doc'ed to have empty implementations, so no need to call super at all c) no need to reference any outer class explicitly, the mouseEvent carries its source

Comment: as [per docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#grabFocus()) *This method is intended for use by focus implementations. Client code should not use this method; instead, it should use `requestFocusInWindow()`*

Answer (score 3):

> Note: My JFrame is set to focusable (true).

for example

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JPanelAndFocus {

    private JFrame frm = new JFrame("JPanel_And_Focus");
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField one = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField two = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField three = new JTextField(10);

    public JPanelAndFocus() {
        //panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(one);
        panel.add(two);
        panel.add(three);
        panel.setFocusable(true);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 //delayed should be important for events from DocumentListener / InputMask
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //panel.requestFocus();
                        panel.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        frm.add(panel);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocation(400, 300);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //one.requestFocus();
                one.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanelAndFocus jpaf = new JPanelAndFocus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: nitpicks: a) call the one or other of the requestFocus methods, not both b) no need for the invokeLater in the mousePressed (we are on the edt and likely no other events pending that we might want to wait for) c) no need for setting the FlowLayout, it's the default as we all know :-)

Answer (score 2):

Whereas the different methods cited above didn't work for me, meaning that the focus remained on the JButton, I find e.getSource() works to set the component focus right

```
YourContainerPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent clicked = (JComponent)e.getSource();
        clicked.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but also explain your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.getParent().requestFocus()
```